# How to use cloud-init with a debian-based image on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, cloud-init

Following terraform [best practice](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/f6e648cc8b4e34242c5f5df144778614b98c6ef8/website/docs/provisioners/index.html.markdown#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources) for bootstrapping instances, I'm working on a `cloud-init` config in order to bootstrap my instance. My only need is to install a specific package.

My terraform config looks like this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "bastion" {
  name         = "my-first-instance"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "europe-west1-b"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = "eugene:${file("/Users/eugene/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}"
    user-data = file("my_cloud_init.conf")
  }
}
```

Following [example](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-arbitrary-packages) for installing packages from `cloud-init` docs, here's the contents of `my_cloud_init.conf`:

```
#cloud-config

packages:
 - kubectl
```

After running `terraform plan -out myplan` and `terraform apply myplan`, I ssh onto the node only to find `kubectl` not available. Moreover, there's no evidence that `cloud-init` was run or that it exists on the node:

```
$ which -a cloud-init
$ cat /var/log/cloud-init
cat: /var/log/cloud-init: No such file or directory
```

Looking for clues about usage of `cloud-init` with Google Cloud Compute instances wasn't fruitful:

- "[Google Cloud Engine](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/gce.html)" page from `cloud-init` docs suggests settings `user-data` to a `cloud-init` config should be enough,
- I see a `cloud-init` [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#using_cloud-init), but it's for `Container Optimized OS`,
- there are [some clues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/search?q=%22cloud-init%22&unscoped_q=%22cloud-init%22&type=Issues) about `cloud-init` on other images, but nothing indicates `cloud-init` is available on `debian-cloud/debian-9`,
- there's "[Running startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)", but it has no mention of `cloud-init`.

I don't mind using another image, as long as it's Debian or Ubuntu and I don't have to make an image template myself.

**How to use `cloud-init` with a debian-based image on Google Cloud? What am I missing?**

Comment: I don't have to work on kubectl, but also need docs on cloud-init for GCP and here's what I found: A [request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1816) to add it to docs, then the [open MR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-template/pull/35) in official docs on hashicorp website, and that's how I found the [incomplete documentation](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-template/blob/master/website/docs/d/cloudinit_config.html.markdown) for that. Unfortunately it's still an AWS-specific doc, but just set base64 and gziping to `false`. Helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cloud-init` is installed on the latest (at the moment of writing) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (`ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20191002`) image :

```
<my_user>@instance-1:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"

<my_user>@instance-1:~$ which cloud-init
/usr/bin/cloud-init
```

You should replace `debian-cloud/debian-9` with `ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20191002`.

Comment: Thank you, @norbjd! Did you know this from experience, or were you able to look it up just now? The reason I am asking is because googling failed me, and I want to understand how to properly search for it next time.

Comment: I just checked by starting an Ubuntu instance :) Sadly, I don't know how to find what packages are installed on a specific public image without trying.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248537/80851) from **[@norbjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7804058/norbjd)**, posting this for completeness:

- in order to install `kubectl` package that I planned initially, I had to write this `cloud-init` config:

  ```
    #cloud-config

    bootcmd:
     - curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add

    apt:
      sources:
        kubernetes.list:
          source: "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"

    packages:
     - kubectl
  ```
- if you need to know which images contain which packages, these resources may be helpful:

  - Ubuntu:

    - [Ubuntu Cloud Images (RELEASED)](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/)
    - Actual contents (example):

      - https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/23.04/release-20230729/ubuntu-23.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.manifest
  - Debian:

    - [List of differences between standard and cloud systems](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/SystemsComparison)
    - Actual contents:

      - https://salsa.debian.org/cloud-team/debian-cloud-images/-/blob/master/config_space/sid/package_config/EXTRAS
      - https://salsa.debian.org/cloud-team/debian-cloud-images/-/blob/master/config_space/sid/package_config/CLOUD